# Adding blank spaces to a list during a set time period

Tags: c#, wpf, list, mvvm, listbox

I am creating a WPF application using MVVM. I am wanting to create a basic list of bookings for a certain date that are pulled back from a database, but also include blank spaces in the list (to be displayed in a listbox) to show when there is free time in between bookings, during working hours.

So far I can get blank spaces adding but only for the empty gaps within 2 bookings, whereas I want the spaces to be displayed for every hour from 9:00 until 21:00.

```
private void CheckForGaps(List<DisplayBookingDetails> list)
{
    DateTime endIndex;
    DateTime startIndex;
    int minBookingLength = 60;

    DisplayBookingDetails[] test;
    DisplayBookingDetails nullMarker = null;

    DateTime dayStart = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01).AddHours(09).AddMinutes(00).AddSeconds(00);
    DateTime dayEnd = new DateTime(0001, 01, 01).AddHours(21).AddMinutes(00).AddSeconds(00);


    test = list.ToArray();
    List<DisplayBookingDetails> testList = new List<DisplayBookingDetails>();

    for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            endIndex = list[i - 1].EndTime;
            startIndex = list[i].StartTime;
            int diff = ((int)(startIndex - endIndex).TotalMinutes);

            testList.Add(test[i - 1]);

            while (diff >= minBookingLength)
            {
                nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = endIndex.ToShortTimeString(), End = endIndex.AddMinutes(60).ToShortTimeString() };
                testList.Add(nullMarker);
                diff -= minBookingLength;
            }
        }
    }
    if (test.Length > 0)
        testList.Add(test[test.Length - 1]);
        DisplayBookingDetails = testList;
    }
```

The code above goes through the array and if it isn't empty it checks the differences between bookings and adds the null marker row in the list, but I would like this display empty rows even if the date has no bookings at all.

Does anyone know how I could go about adding this functionality, thanks?[image: This shows what the functionality already displays]

[image: 2nd screenshot provided of latest display]

Comment: why not start i at 1, since it needs to be > 0 to do anything?

Comment: I used 0 because it is using an array and the 1st value is stored at 0

Comment: well yes, and 1 - 1 = 0, which is where you will be starting.  I believe my answer should do exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you create test instead of using list, but I have completely altered your code to do exactly what you want.

```
private void CheckForGaps(List<DisplayBookingDetails> list)
{
    DateTime endPrevious;
    DateTime startCurrent;
    int minBookingLength = 60;

    DisplayBookingDetails nullMarker = null;

    DateTime selectedDate = [CalendarObject].Value.Date;

    DateTime dayStart = selectedDate.AddHours(09)
    DateTime dayEnd = selectedDate.AddHours(21)

    List<DisplayBookingDetails> testList = new List<DisplayBookingDetails>();

    if (list.Length > 0) // First we check if the list has any items
    {
        DateTime startTime = dayStart;
        DateTime endTime = list[0].StartTime;
        // Fill the gap before the first appointment with blank appointments
        while ((endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes >= minBookingLength)
        {
            nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = startTime.ToShortTimeString(), End = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength).ToShortTimeString() };
            testList.Add(nullMarker);
            startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength);
        }
        // Go through the appointments adding them
        for (int i = 1; i < list.Length; i++)
        {
            testList.Add(list[i - 1]);

            endPrevious = list[i - 1].EndTime;
            startCurrent = list[i].StartTime;

            startTime = endPrevious;
            // Fill gaps between appointments
            while ((startCurrent - startTime).TotalMinutes >= minBookingLength)
            {
                nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = startTime.ToShortTimeString(), End = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength).ToShortTimeString() };
                testList.Add(nullMarker);
                startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength);
            }
        }
        // Add the last appointment
        testList.Add(list[list.Length - 1]);

        // Add blank appointments after the last appointment until End of Day
        startTime = list[list.Length - 1].EndTime;
        while ((dayEnd - startTime).TotalMinutes >= minBookingLength)
        {
            nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = startTime.ToShortTimeString(), End = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength).ToShortTimeString() };
            testList.Add(nullMarker);
            startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength);
        }
    }
    else // No items in list, add all blank appointments
    {
        DateTime startTime = dayStart;
        while((dayEnd - startTime).TotalMinutes >= minBookingLength)
        {
            nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = startTime.ToShortTimeString(), End = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength).ToShortTimeString() };
            testList.Add(nullMarker);
            startTime = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength);
        }
    }
    // Display the final list
    DisplayBookingDetails.ItemsSource = testList;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you help, it appears to do what I need it to but it is crashing at this point: 
"// Fill the gap before the first appointment with blank appointments
        while ((endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes >= minBookingLength)
        {
            nullMarker = new DisplayBookingDetails(0) { Start = startTime.ToShortTimeString(), End = startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength).ToShortTimeString() };
            testList.Add(nullMarker);
            startTime.AddMinutes(minBookingLength);
        }"

Going into an infinite loop and the start and end times never get past 9:00 and 10:00

Comment: I feel like an idiot... ok, so I added the time, but I forgot to set that back to startTime.  Make sure you change all the while loops where I changed them.

Comment: Just so you know, I am the king of infinite loops for stupid reasons, and that is one that I have done plenty of times within my own code...

Comment: Don't worry about it, I appreciate all the help since I am new to C# and MVVM. This solved the time issue, but it is still crashing at the same point because the loop is not stopping when it reaches the day end time

Comment: That is because of the fact that the dates don't match up.  If you change your dates in your DateTime objects to the selected day (3/31/14 for the example shown), that makes a difference.  I'll update my answer again.  Just FYI, the CalendarObject is whatever you named it.  I'm not really sure what you would have named it, so I just left it generic.  The .Date at the end gets just the date part, and that means you can add the time to exactly when you want it to be.  I think this will finish up the problem you've had.

Comment: I believe that will fix the last of your problems, but if not, somebody else might have to step in and help.  I'm about to head home for the day.

Comment: Alternatively, you can pass the date to the function with the list of bookings if you already get it in the function that calls this one.

Comment: The system has stopped crashing with the latest edit, but now the list has hundreds of entries with times for the selected dates repeating themselves, but I will hopefully be able to solve this issue myself. Thanks

Comment: Can you update with a new screenshot on that, I'm home now and maybe I can help figure out the rest of it.

Comment: I have provided a new screenshot of the latest output

Comment: OK, so is it just repeating the same things over and over again?  I'm trying to figure out how it would be doing that unless it is just funning this function many times and just adding all of them to the end each time.  You may want to start this function with a `DisplayBookingDetails.Items.Clear()` or something along those lines.

Comment: If all of this works, don't forget to accept the answer.

Comment: Even better idea would be to change the last line to `DisplayBookingDetails.ItemsSource = TestList`;

 (Changed my answer with this)

Comment: Yes I will accept the answer because I am very close to getting it working properly. Clearing DisplayBookingDetails at the start of the function stops the duplication, but it also wipes the bookings that do exist from the list

Comment: You can try my alternate solution by making testList the ItemsSource, or you can just make the original list a global variable within the form and set list = testList at the end of the function since it seems like it is the current ItemsSource for the listbox.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! It appears to be working correctly now, so I accepted your answer :)

Comment: Cool.  I'm glad I could be of assistance.